# Django views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

Hey guys I am running a blog with Django on a server but the contact form is not working, and after messing with it a bit, I broke it but the code is the original so I have no idea why it wouldn't be working. Here is my contact form:

```
def contact(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('subject', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a subject.')
        if not request.POST.get('message', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a message.')
        if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
            errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
        if not errors:
            send_mail(
                request.POST['subject'],
                "User's Email:              " + request.POST['email'] + "           User's Message:     " + request.POST['message'],
                request.POST.get('email', 'my_email@mail.com'),
                ['my_email@mail.com'], #email address where message is sent.
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    return render(request, 'contact.html',
        {'errors': errors})
```

Now I get this error when I run this page in the site:

```
ValueError at /contact/

The view blog.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Request Method:     GET
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the indentation on your final `return render...` line. This is the behavior you'd see if you had accidentally indented it too far, making it only trigger as part of the `if request.method == 'POST':` block.

Comment: You should be using a Django form for all this logic.

Comment: Just got off work, I will try these things tomorrow I am beat. Thank you guys SO much for responding.

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
return render_to_response(request, 'contact.html',
    {'errors': errors})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect at other view, I advice you to use :

```
return redirect(<name of a view>, permanent=True)
```

instead of `HttpResponseRedirecter`

Comment: You probably don't want a permanent redirect on form submission.

Answer (score 1):

So I did what Peter suggested, checking the indentation of the last return statement (needed to not be indented) and yes... that was it. It's almost like I knew I was going to overlook something like this :p thanks to Peter and everybody for your help, I really appreciate you guys!! Have a good weekend